# Side Effects of Binding Errors?

Tags: xaml, binding

I have a `UserControl` that I'm using as a template for two classes. This works fine because they both have the same property names. However, one of them has a few properties that the other one doesn't. This leads to binding errors in my Output window when binding to the class without the extra properties. It still works fine and the user can't even tell there was an error, but my question is: Are there any undesirable side effects caused by this?

(For the record, I plan to use `x:DeferLoadStrategy` to just not render the fields if not necessary. I'm merely curious about this.)

Comment: My question would be, how hard really is it to add fallbacks and targetnulls and such to handle any such situations anyway. Oh and careful with the Defer dude, the more you do that, the bigger the memory footprint.

Comment: @ChrisW. It's not. As the question states, it's not an unsolvable issue, just something I'm curious about. What? Setting it to "Lazy" uses *less* memory, not more.

Comment: Sorry amigo but that's not correct. Read the first paragraph of [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt204785.aspx) on Lazy. Although I'm curious about the original question also as to what potential side effects occur of unseen error reporting at runtime.

Comment: Ah my bad. The startup time is what I was thinking of, not memory usage. Oh well, looks like the extra memory usage is still so minute you'd have to severely abuse it to actually notice the effects.

Comment: Yea, I saw a guy go crazy with it though on hundreds of objects once. He was all excited until he went from the sim to the device and killed it lol.

Comment: Haha yeah I'm nowhere near that yet, but will keep an eye on it.